# How to correctly read bitstreams in Python

Tags: python, io, streamlink

Tell me how to write bitstreams correctly

Here is my code, it works, but it seems to me that I am not writing data to the file correctly.

```
fd = stream.open()
filename = 'file.ts'
while True:
    data = fd.read(8192)
    file_output = open(filename, "ab")
    file_output.write(data)
```

fd is a data stream, it is replenished and, accordingly, I must read from it until it ends.

Comment: What *seems* wrong with your code?

Comment: fd = stream.open() in this line I am reading a stream from streamlink as a ts file.  Next, I need to write it to a file while the stream is running.  It's hard for me to think of how to do this in Python.

Comment: Let me clarify. You've said your code works. So what is your question?

Comment: https://streamlink.github.io/api_guide.html from this api, I get a stream and I need to write it to a file.  Yes, the code does not work correctly, but it works.  I want to understand how to write a stream of bytes correctly while they are in the fd container.